# How to apply a random number to every cell in matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to apply randomness to each of the elements in my matrix. I have provided a MWE below.

```
x_len = 1000;
y_len = 100;
x = 0:1:x_len;
y = 0:1:y_len;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

Z = (0.04 * X);
for i = 1:(x_len * y_len)
    rand = rand();
    Z = Z + rand;
end
```

This of course just applies the *same* random number to each cell in the matrix `(x_len * y_len)` times. I would like each cell to have a different random number added to it. I have searched, and feel like this should be a simple thing, but I'm failing to recognize the syntax needed. Thanks. AM.

Comment: btw the word `cell` refers to a specific thing in MATLAB, which I don't think you are talking about here.. Also you are creating a variable called `rand` which shadows the builtin function `rand` (obviously bad!)

Comment: For questions like these, reading the help is often instructive and quickest. Just type `help rand` or `doc rand` into command window – more useful than Google or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can just write:

```
Z = Z + rand(size(Z));
```

where `Z` is your M-by-N matrix.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm teaching myself here, and sometimes I have difficulty finding pointers on simple things like this; things that are not in the docs, like horchler mentioned. Also, thanks for the tips above, I will keep in mind.

Comment: @amoodie This IS in the docs! Did you read the `rand` help? Horchler was saying that the docs are good!

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear. I see now that it is in the docs, but I have trouble understanding what things mean without being able to see the result. I should have experimented around a bit more first. Thanks all.